# Bug in sn-jnl.cls with iicol mode and multiple affiliations

Tags: errors, document-classes, springernature

When using the Springer Nature `sn-jnl.cls` class file, the use of `iicol` mode leads to incorrect author affiliations if there are multiple affiliations. How to fix this?

MRE: open the template [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/springer-nature-latex-template/myxmhdsbzkyd), try to compile and confirm that author affiliations are correct:

[image: Correct author affiliations]

Change the `\documentclass` line from

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys,Numbered]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Reference Style
```

to:

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys,Numbered,iicol]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Reference Style
```

Compile and note author affiliations are now wrong:

[image]

Comment: I meet the same issue. Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: You've found a bug, check you're using the latest version (if not maybe report the emplate as out of date to Overleaf/Springer), if it's a bug in the latest version report it to the maintainer (Springer).

Comment: @DaiBowen will do so. But I’m not sure how long they’ll take to fix it, and I have to submit a paper using this style. Hence I was wondering if someone could help debug it so I don’t have to depend on Springer’s response time.

Comment: Sure, it's fair to ask, I had a quick look, but `iicol` doesn't obviously change anything relevant to the issue and I don't fancy giving Springer free labour trying to debug further.  It's unlikely (as the tex code is unambiguous and submissions probably solicit the metadata independently) to cause any real issue with submission though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. For me, the below works.

In **sn-jnl.cls** file line 501, replace

```
      \@for\@@affmark:=#1\do{\edef\affnum{\@ifundefined{X@\@@affmark}{1}{\jmkRef{\@@affmark}}}%
```

by

```
      \@for\@@affmark:=#1\do{\edef\affnum{\@ifundefined{X@\@@affmark}{\@@affmark}{\jmkRef{\@@affmark}}}%
```

Do same thing for lines 507~516.

I hope this works for you.
[image]